# Поиск по DataGridView C#, не могу создать сообщение об ошибке поиска

Tags: c#, datagridview

Поиск осуществляется по тексту из текстбокса в `DataGridView`. При совпадении строка выделяется, вот если ничего не найдено, просто вся таблица остается белой. Нужно выдавать сообщение, что ничего не найдено. Как реализовать сообщение в таком коде?:

```
private void Findb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < contackListDataGridView.RowCount; i++)
    {
        contackListDataGridView.Rows[i].Selected = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < contackListDataGridView.ColumnCount; j++)
            if (contackListDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)

                if (contackListDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(FindBox.Text.ToLower()))
                {
                    contackListDataGridView.Rows[i].Selected = true;

                    break;
                }


    }
}
```

Comment: А что тут сложного?Добавить Else

Comment: Лучше искать напрямую в данных, которые для `DataGridView` являются `DataSource`, а не строить трёхэтажные конструкции для пробежки по строкам и столбцам визуального контрола коим является `DataGridView`.

Comment: Но потом все равно придется искать в DataGridView что бы выделить выбранные строки :)